# Visual Studio 2019 Community has a trial extension license

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 and in the installer there were some versions of VS 2019 so I installed the *professional* version: [The installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAJci.png). And after that I enter the program and this popped up when I clicked on my profile settings: [VS Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IABYv.png). **So does that mean VS Pro will only stay until the specified date?** And if so why is it in the free installer?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one Visual Studio installer. It installs all free and paid editions of Visual Studio. (Though it is preconfigured to launch the setup for a specific edition.)

You will have to install Visual Studio Community instead. It is the only free edition. I strongly suggest you first install Visual Studio Community and then uninstall Professional. Because most components are already installed (with Professional), it will be a lot faster this way.

Comment: I actually uninstalled Professional already, but thank you very much!